# Simple chrome redirect extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I intend to create a simple chrome extension (for personal use) that simply detects when the user opens a new tab and redirects him to a certain website. The redirection url can be set in the source code, there is no need for some kind of form to submit it (since this will be, like I said, mostly just used by me and I can change that value easily in the code).

The problem is I don't know where to start from or how to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've read google's "Getting started: Building a chrome extension" by the way.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should probably ask in the programming forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an extension sometime ago and published it to the chrome webstore https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instructables-default-all/oeeoefddkogaamghjjoelcgmellpacid?hl=en the source code is available here http://code.nishantarora.in/instructables-default-all-steps-chrome-extension/src

The purpose of this extension is to redirect a user opening an instructable on instructables.com should be shown the url appended with ?ALLSTEPS to load the all steps page for that particular instructable. The code is pretty easy to understand.